# Migrating from Googlecode to Github with full revision history

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn, google-code

Trying to migrate an SVN project to Github I first followed the following instructions to turn SVN into Git: http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ConvertingSvnToGit

This worked but I'm unsure what to do next to move from Googlecode to Github.

I've tried:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:GITHUB_USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git
$ git push --all origin
```

(I hope that makes sense because I'm just guessing here)

It then tells me I should do a pull before I can push. But it pulls from Googlecode off course. **So how do I tell it to pull from Github?**

_

*(I did also see this: http://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git ... should I try it that way?)*

Comment: What is the name of your git-svn remote? You can find it with `git remote`

Answer (score 1):

Ah far easier than I anticipated (but since I don't know any Git command line I didn't know where to start)...

Because my original repo was still on googlecode

```
$ git pull
```

would just pull from there.

```
$ git pull origin master
```

Did the trick. Had to add the branch (master) because origin is not the default remote.
Then a

```
$ git push --all origin
```

and I'm ready to rock and roll

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you want to take:

- Use git-svn to checkout your google code
- Create your github repo
- Add your github repo as a remote
- Pull your code from the git-svn repo `git-svn rebase trunk` <-- I think you are here
- Push the code to your new remote `git push origin master`

That should be it.

Comment: I don't think I'm exactly there since I followed a different route, but ok. What does rebase do? ... and doesn't 'push origin master' only apply to the latest revision?

Comment: git-svn rebase pulls the entire truno down and puts any code revisions you made on top.

Comment: git push origin master pushes the entire master branch, with ALL revisions, to origin